# Potentially Dangerous request errors

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am hosting my apllications. They are running under .net version 4.0. Everything is working fine. But lately, i am getting error list "Potentially Dangerous request ...". I searched on the internet and found out have i have to set my web.config like this.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

It it is use then the problem is solved. and my question is                           how to solve the error without using page validate request set false.

is other way able to solve the problem???

Comment: I would find out what is causing the errors before switching that flag off. It's usual when an input or something contains html and the server blocks it. Sometimes when you have an HTML editor on the site it can cause problems if you don't encode before posting.

Comment: Also, what comes after  "Potentially Dangerous request ...". it will usually say something like ...request.form value or ...request.querystring value. This will help pinpoint what part of the request was potentially dangerous.

Comment: MVC or WebForms?

Comment: i have use webforms